# Parse.User.logIn() return [Object object]

Tags: html, node.js, parse-platform

My problem is that when I use the `Parse.User.logIn()` or the `Parse.User.signUp` methods it successfully register the user and adds it to the database but when I try log out the user info after i created the user or logged the user in it returns `[Object object]`.

My server script

```
// Require Node Modules
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    ParseCloud = require('parse-cloud-express'),
    Parse = ParseCloud.Parse;
var app = express();
var hogan = require('hogan.js');
var user_data;


/**
* Middleware functions
**/

require('./cloud/main.js');
Parse.initialize("H3zIfzbI2BFXmze3sZwOwsBUIf2sxstwQd2oXnjx", "qciO1WFPWdXBdHMyCBuroSN2EzZr46vB4HJBFsxM", "i3KDD1e3W1whxQpfPVv10mXxeJQfeU4HkRAqiDm7");
app.use('/webhooks', ParseCloud.app);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended": "true"}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', "html");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

function isAuthenticated(req, res) {
   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
   if (currentUser) {
      console.log('User is authenticated!');
   } else {
      console.log('User is not authenticated and needs to authenticate');
      res.redirect('/');
   }
}

// Define a Cloud Code function:
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hello from Cloud Code on Node.');
});


/**
* The home page for those who are not signed in
**/
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/main.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   var username = req.body.username;
   var password = req.body.password;
   var email = req.body.email;
   var full_name = req.body.full_name;

   var user = new Parse.User();
   user.set("username", username);
   user.set("password", password);
   user.set("email", email);
   user.set("full_name", full_name);

   user.signUp(null, {
      success: function (user) {
         console.log("User successfully created: " + user);
      },
      error: function (user, error) {
         console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
   });
});

/**
* App login page anf functions
**/
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/login.html");
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
   Parse.User.logIn(req.body.log_username, req.body.log_password, {
      success: function(user) {
         console.log("Logged in: " + user);
         // user_data = user;
         // res.render(__dirname + '/public/views/dashboard.html');
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
         console.log("Error: " + error + "\n" + user);
         // res.send('Incorrect credentials mate!');
      }
   });
});

/**
* This is the routes and function for the user to reset theor password.
**/

app.get('/resetPassword', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/resetPassword.html");
});

app.post('/resetPassword', function (req, res) {
   Parse.User.requestPasswordReset(req.body.reset_email, {
      success: function () {
         // TODO: Notify the user in the window that the password was successfully reset
         console.log('Password reset successful.');
      },
      error: function (error) {
         // TODO: Notify the user in the window something went wrong.
         console.log('Error: ' + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
   });
});


/**
* The main user dashboard
**/
app.get('/dashboard', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
   res.render(__dirname + "/public/views/dashboard.html", {
      user: user_data
   });
});


/*
 * Launch the HTTP server
 */
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Cloud Code Webhooks server running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Affinity - Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Quicksand:400,300,700|Josefin+Slab:400,300italic,400italic,600,700|Julius+Sans+One|Pompiere|Gruppo|Flamenco:400,300|Bubbler+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/main.css">
   </head>

   <body class="login-background">

      <div class="main-container container">
         <div class="row">

            <!-- Brand and navbar -->
            <div class="main-navbar col-md-12">
               <a href="/"><h1 class="brand">Affinity</h1></a>
               <ul>
                  <li><span class="ion-social-snapchat"></span></li>
                  <li><span class="ion-social-twitter"></span></li>
                  <li><span class="ion-social-instagram-outline"></span></li>
                  <li><span class="ion-social-github"></span></li>
                  <li><span class="ion-social-googleplus"></span></li>
                  <li><span class="ion-social-facebook"></span></li>
               </ul>
            </div>

            <!--================== Login form ================-->
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div id="log-form">
                 <h2 class="log-form-title">Welcome Back</h2>
                 <p class="form-para">Log in and start coding like there's no tomrrow</p>
                 <form class="log-form col s12" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="log_email" type="text" class="validate" name="log_username">
                        <label for="log_username">Username</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="log_password" type="password" class="validate" name="log_password">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="log_submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Login</button>
                    <p class="forgot-pass">Forgot password? <a href="#">Reset now!</a></p>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!--==================END OF LOGIN FORM ===============-->

         </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SCRIPTS -->
      <!-- JQuery CDN -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Custom scripts -->
      <script src="../scripts/auth_handling.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

can someone please help me!

Comment: i think they just removed some string representation for the Parse objects... you can use id of the object with "object.id" or some other property "object.get("columnName")"

Comment: this works and returns the users id but when i try return username or something like email it doesn't work what i did was `console.log(user.id + " " + user.username);` which return id but 'undefined' for username.